# searching a tuple list with wildcards?

Tags: python, list, tuples

how can I search a list of tuples if I only know 1 element of any tuple in the list?

mockup example (this doesn't work):

```
tuplelist = [('cat', 'dog'), ('hello', 'goodbye'), ('pretty', 'ugly')]
matchlist = []
searchstring = 'goodbye'

if (*, searchstring) in tuplelist:
    print "match was found"
    matchlist.append(tuplelist[#index of match])
```

the asterix would be where I want to put the wildcard

I know I could use:

```
for i in range (len(tuplelist)):
    if tuplelist[i][1]==searchstring:
        matchlist.append(tuplelist[i])
        print "match was found"
```

but the problem is that I need to run a specific function only once if no match is found.

maybe I could make a counter that increments when a match is found and add something like this to the loop.

```
    if i==len(tuplelist) and matchcounter==0:
        #do something
        print "no match was found"
```

But that's kind of ugly and confusing I think and I'm sure there's some cleaner way to do this :P

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. It's not really clear what your requirements are. In your first example you are only testing if there is a match, in your second example you are doing something for each match.

Comment: @Mark Byers: He mentions that is a problem with his second example immediately after it.

Comment: @robert: Perhaps but it's not clear whether he just forgot to insert a break statement or if that was intentional. A clear description of what he's *actually* trying to do with a worked example would help clear things up. So far there are four answers and each of them seem to be answering a completely different question. I think that's evidence that the question is not clear enough in its current form.

Comment: sorry if the question is vague.  The lack of break statements was intentional. I want to search only the second element of every tuple in the list and when a match is found I want to append that tuple to a second list and keep iterating since there could be more then 1 match.  But if there is no match I want to run a different function, but if I put that inside an 'else' statement inside the same loop then that would run the 'no match' function for every item in the list.

Comment: Please do not comment on your question.  Please **update** the question to be completely clear.  It's your question.  You can improve it so that everyone understands it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this:

```
found_match = False

for t in tuplelist:
    if t[1] == searchstring:
        #do something
        print "match was found"
        found_match = True

if not found_match:
    # ...
```

Comment: haha... this is perfect and so obvious, I'm in serious need of sleep.  thanks brah

Comment: note that another way of saying this is: any(t[1] == searchstring for t in tuplelist)

Answer (score 7):

I'm amazed that no one has really pointed this out yet and this is a rather old question but I'll leave this here in case someone stumbled upon this like myself.

There is a for...else construct in Python just for this use case. You can do this(I'm going to use Mark Byers' code and change it):

```
for t in tuplelist:
    if t[1] == searchstring:
        #do something
        print "match was found"
        break
else:
    print "not matches found"
    # call function if not matches were found.
```

The else section only happens if the loop exits normally(no breaks).

Answer (score 4):

I **think** you're trying to do partial ordered matching;
the following uses None as a wildcard:

```
def tupleMatch(a,b):
    return len(a)==len(b) and all(i is None or j is None or i==j for i,j in zip(a,b))

def tupleCombine(a,b):
    return tuple([i is None and j or i for i,j in zip(a,b)])

def tupleSearch(findme, haystack):
    return [tupleCombine(findme,h) for h in haystack if tupleMatch(findme, h)]

findme = (None, "goodbye")
haystack = [
    ('cat', 'dog'),
    ('hello', 'goodbye'),
    ('pretty', 'ugly'),
    ('tomorrow', 'goodbye'),
    ('goodbye', 'today'),
    ('anything', None)
]
tupleSearch(findme, haystack)
```

returns

```
[('hello', 'goodbye'), ('tomorrow', 'goodbye'), ('anything', 'goodbye')]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a list comprehension to generate a new list of only the elements you care about.  For example:

```
tuplelist = [('cat', 'dog'), ('hello', 'goodbye'), ('pretty', 'ugly')]
if 'goodbye' in (x[1] for x in tuplelist):
    print "match was found"
```

This takes the list of tuples and constructs the list (actually a generator expression) containing only the second elements from each tuple; then it tests the search string for membership in that new list.

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(x,y): return 'did something with (%s,%s)' % (str(x), str(y))

matches = [f(a,b) for a,b in tuplelist if b == searchstring]
if not matches:
    #do something else
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pairs = [('cat', 'dog'), ('hello', 'goodbye'), ('pretty', 'ugly')]
matches = [p for p in pairs if p[1] == 'goodbye']
```

Done. No fuss, no muss. You're trying too hard to do things the way you'd do them in imperative languages. Stop trying to tell Python how to do things, and tell it what to do.

> but the problem is that I need to run a specific function only once if no match is found.

... So check the list afterward: if it's empty, then no match was found. What's the problem?